# character array type in C

Tags: c, types

What is the type of the following array variable `message`:

```
char message[] = "got it";
```

`char *` or `char [7]` or `char (*)[7]`?

Comment: It's `char[7]`.

Comment: Easy way to find out:   `char (*a)[7] = &message; char **b = &message; char (**p)[7] = &message;`.

Comment: You may find it useful to read the section on arrays vs. pointers in any good C tutorial. I like [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language).

Comment: However when `message` appears in the right hand side of an assignment operator `=`, it is treated as  `char *`

Comment: @user3477487 because that's one of the many contexts where an array *decays* to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char message[] = "got it";
```

*message* is a character array of size 7. It is not a pointer, try `message++;` compiler will throw an error.